# Python Xgboost GridSearchCV killed, how to fix?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, grid-search

I'm new to xgboost on Python and today I was trying to follow the tutorial here: https://jessesw.com/XG-Boost/.

Then I tried xgboost using my own data, it works fine without using gridsearch. Then I followed the tutorial to do the gridsearch but looks like it does not work. This is my code:

```
cv_params = {'max_depth': [3, 5, 7], 'min_child_weight': [1, 3, 5]}
ind_params = {'learning_rate': 0.1, 'n_estimators': 500, 'seed': 0,
          'subsample': 0.8, 'colsample_bytree': 0.8,
          'objective': 'reg:linear'}

optimized_GBM = GridSearchCV(xgb.XGBClassifier(**ind_params),
                         cv_params,
                         cv=5, n_jobs=2, verbose=2)

optimized_GBM.fit(train_x, train['label'])
```

And I got this output:

```
Fitting 5 folds for each of 9 candidates, totalling 45 fits
[CV] max_depth=3, min_child_weight=1................................      
//anaconda/bin/python.app: line 3:   906 Killed: 9        //anaconda/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you check it on other system? It seems python interpreter crashes.

Comment: @IbraimGaniev just ran the same code on another computer but the result is the same

Comment: Solved. Since this is a regression problem, we are supposed to use XGBRegressor() instead XGBClassifier(). Was using R before so didn't realize the difference in Python.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was in colsample_by_tree. It was 0.1, when the total number of features was less than 10.

And the reason of fail was an assertion, when tree is trying to learn on dataset with n samples and 0 features.